# jquery and dependsOn basics

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a PHP/MySQL system. On one form I have a number of data entry elements including a check box (called '`conflict`'). If someone checks this box then I want a section to appear that show a text box ('notes').

I have never used jquery before and so am trying a simple example which just doesn't work for me as, instead of seeing the text box only when I check the checkbox, I see it all of the time.

The code I am using is shown below and both jquery.js and dependson.js are in the same folder as the page.

Can anybody help please? (Sorry this is such a basic question!)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dependson.js"></script>

</head>

      <script>

$('#myText').dependsOn({
    // The selector for the depenency
    '#myCheck': {
        // The dependency qualifiers
        enabled: true,
        checked: true
    }
});
</script>


<form id="myForm">
    <label for="myCheck">Check Me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

    <label for="myText">Input</label>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
</form>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all your form is not inside the body and secondly move the script portion before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thank you - I tried that but it still didn't work.

Comment: Take a look a the following [**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cBOnRnXzv0Oxj62tMIJJ?p=preview).

Comment: Excellent - that now works well. Many thanks